# Jquery Mobile not displaying data-icons (correctly)

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, popup, navbar

So, I'm adding a popup menu off the header and it works... works quite well actually except for one small thing. For the life of me I can't get it to display the icons the way I want them!

In the first <li> I brute force the data-icon into the <li> and it shows but its not positioned to the left.  In the others, I left the data-icon where I'm accustomed to leaving them (where they work correctly everywhere else) and they don't display at all.

Any suggestions?

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1>MyApp</h1>
  <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right"> Menu </a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="left"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-icon="location">GPS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /header -->
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppetree/nx5tp2b6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-iconpos attribute not defined for regular list items, works only when the < li> item is inside a navbar widget: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_ref_data.asp

Please, take a look to the fiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/xbo8npng/1/

I have placed the icons to the left using css:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
  <h1>MyApp</h1>
  <a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right"> Menu </a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li class="left" data-icon="gear"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li class="left"><a href="#" data-icon="location">GPS</a></li>
      <li class="left"><a href="#" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the styles:

```
 .left a{
        padding-left: 2.5em !important;
        padding-right: 1em !important;
  }
  .left a:after{
        left: 2px;
        right: auto;
  }
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: This solves the problem but it doesn't explain why data-iconpos="left" isn't working or why data-icon inside the <a> isn't working.

Comment: it never occurred to me that data-iconpos wouldn't be applied to all elements. I must be getting old! ;-)